# Collect Data from NEXT item while in loop

Tags: custom-field, loop

I am trying to get the value of a custom field. The trick? I'm in the loop, currently printing out 2 of 5 for this example. I would like to get some info from 3 of 5 (or even 1 of 5) while printing out info on 2 of 5. I hope that makes sense. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you posted no code and little in the way of exactly what criteria you are using, I can't really writ functioning code but inside your Loop try:

```
var_dump($posts[$wp_query->current_post -1]->post_title);
```

That is, `$posts[$wp_query->current_post -1]` is the previous post. You can change `-1` to plus or minus whatever value you want but the math cannot result is a figure below `0` or above your posts_per_page -1 (I think), as those don't exist. The query only gets posts on "this page". If you do need information from posts that appear on a previous or next page you will have to query for that information.

Comment: I didn't post any code because it was a very abstract question. I was looking for an approach that wasn't dependent on my code, something that I could put in any loop. You hit the nail on the head. That is what I came up with after digging a little deeper, too. Thanks!

`$events->posts[ $events->current_post + 1 ];`

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have access to a posts array and the loop variable directly (for example, when customizing WooCommerce product loop with actions):

```php
global $wp_query;

// Previous product ID
echo $wp_query->posts[$wp_query->current_post - 1]->ID;

// Current product ID
echo the_ID(); 

// Next product ID
echo $wp_query->posts[$wp_query->current_post + 1]->ID;
```